# Replace string in a for loop

Tags: batch-file

I want to strip the colon `:` out of each of the element of the list. I'm not clear the string replace syntax in the context of a for loop. How can you manipulate each `%%a`?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions disabledelayedexpansion   

set studies=sign1:chap2,sign2:chap3
for %%a in ("%studies:,=" "%") do (
echo %%~a
set var=%~a::=%
echo study %var%
)
```

Comment: You cannot do string manipulation with a `FOR` token.  Essentially you are trying to manipulate the environmental variable `%a%`. You need to assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable first and then you need to use delayed expansion with that variable to do the string replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Squashman suggestion, this is the solution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion    

set studies=sign1:chap2,sign2:chap3
for %%a in ("%studies:,=" "%") do (
  set temp=%%~na
  echo !temp::=!
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon exactly what you posted…

You could use this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions   
Set "studies=sign1:chap2,sign2:chap3"
Set "}=%studies::=%"
Echo "%}:,=" "%"
Pause
```

For this output:

```
"sign1:chap2" "sign2:chap3"
```

However, as that cannot be your real world issue, because you wouldn't manually define the `studies` variable like that, you'd define it exaclty as you wanted it:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "studies="sign1chap2" "sign2chap3""
Echo %studies%
Pause
```

It is more likely that you're wanting something more like this:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "studies=sign1:chap2,sign2:chap3"
For %%G In (%studies::=%) Do Echo "%%~G"
Pause
```

For this output:

```
"sign1:chap2"
"sign2:chap3"
```

If that's not the case, which I suspect, then I've answered a question you did not mean to ask because you deliberately provided insufficient information for us to provide a robust solution to an actual problem.

Possibly:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
Set "studies=sign1:chap2,sign2:chap3"
For %%G In ("%studies:,=" "%") Do (Set "}=%%~G"
    SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    Echo !}::=!
    EndLocal
)
Pause
```

Or even:

```sh
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions
Set "studies=sign1:chap2,sign2:chap3"
For %%G In (%studies%) Do For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims=:" %%H In ("%%~G") Do Echo %%H%%I
Pause
```

There are many different permutations of answer, but because of your lack of provided information or exact intended results, it is too difficult for us to guess which solution would be the most suitable for your circumstances.